# How To Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am the project owner in my organization and I have the BigQuery Admin role at the organization level. How do I query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT`?

I am using Console and following along with [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#:%7E:text=storage%20usage%20(Preview)-,TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT,-and%20TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_ORGANIZATION%20for) and just trying to view more BigQuery metadata:

```
SELECT * FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT;
```

Error:

```
Not found: Table [My Project ID]:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT was not found in location US
```

I get the same error if I include [My Project ID] in the `SELECT` statement.

Without Project ID:
[image: without project id]

With Project ID:
[image: with project id]

This query does work:

```
SELECT * FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

Comment: I think that because this feature (TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT) is in preview, it is prone to breaking and the documentation may be lagging behind. Just had a similar issue with "OBJECT_PRIVILEGES" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY` is still in Preview and not Generally Available yet.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_storage_timeline_by_views

I just had the same with `TABLE_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the schema and the table, these need to be in the "us-region".

You can see this example.

```
SELECT
 timestamp AS start_time,
 table_name,
 total_logical_bytes
FROM
 `region-REGION`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT
WHERE
 table_schema = "TABLE_SCHEMA"
AND
 table_name = "TABLE_NAME"
ORDER BY
 start_time DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks @Raul, but I am still getting the same "Not found" error.

Comment: @TMo The schema and table are in the  region-us?

Comment: yes. Everything is in region-us.

Comment: @TMo if you add the project name name "[My Project ID]:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_TIMELINE_BY_PROJECT"

Comment: I get the same error with or without the project ID. See Console screenshots that I just added to the SO question.